# HybridAuth Facebook Login - Permissions

Tags: php, facebook, hybridauth

**HybridAuth Facebook Login - Permissions**

After login it never asked for user approval, instead it redirects to the website with the user profile.

Example: After login it supposed to ask the below message.

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.2178-6/851546_620507588026124_290281089_n.png))</sub>

What settings I need to do to display user-approval (like above confirmation) before retrieve user profile and redirect to website. It asked one time when I started testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to set anything  to get this dialog. It's by default and is opened if a new user tries to authenticate the app. Since you have already authenticated the app, it's not shown the next time (why should it be right?)

You can try removing the app from [your applications](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) and then try to login, you will see the dialog again OR change the set of permissions your app is asking, you'll see the dialog in that case also.

So, **the auth dialog is shown only once to a user unless the user removed the app or any new permission is added in the scope**.